# Know which expression in the group matched

Tags: regex, perl

I'm learning regular expressions and I have a question.

Let's say I have the following xml balise.

```
<xml x="5"/>
```

The value of x can be let's say `foo` or `bar`, so I can have

```
<xml foo="6"/>
<xml bar="7"/>
```

I made a regular expression to matches this expression when reading my file and capture the value in the quotes.

```
print $1."\n" if /<xml\s(?:foo|bar)=\"(\d+)\"\/>/;
```

And the output is

```
6
7
```

Now my question is, is there any way to know if it was either `foo` or `bar` that made the regular expression to match?

I'm asking this because I have two arrays when I need to push in one the values of `foo` and in the other one the values of `bar`

I could do:

```
push @fooValues, $1 if /<xml\sfoo=\"(\d+)\"\/>/;
push @barValues, $1 if /<xml\sbar=\"(\d+)\"\/>/;
```

But I feel that it's not the way to go so that's why I wonder if there is a way to know which group matched.

Comment: `print "$1 $2\n" if /<xml\s(foo|bar)="(\d+)"\/>/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a capturing instead of a non-capturing group:

```
print "$1 - $2\n" if m{<xml\s(foo|bar)="(\d+)"/>};
```

Obviously, you have to use some fake data to learn regular expressions, but I hope that you eventually realize that an actual XML Parser is the best tool for working with XML, and not regex's.

Comment: I'm dumb. Thank you :D Yes this is just to learn regular expressions, I need to do it in "plain perl"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the non-capturing construct, `(?:...)`. If you just use parentheses to make a normal capturing group, you'll have either `foo` or `bar` in `$1` and the number in `$2`. Then you can just check the value of `$1` and handle the number appropriately.

You could even use a hash to store the values:

```
$vals[$1] = $2
```

(Also, insert standard warning about parsing xml with regex. That said, if you are *certain* that the xml constructs you'll be parsing are limited to some simple and well-known subset of the xml language, regex may work fine.)